# Git error when updating local branch : Error merging: cannot create directory at ' ': No such file or directory

Tags: git, git-checkout

I'm trying to update my local repository from remote. Usually I use `git pull` and it always worked.

One of the contributor added files in a path that he created. the path contains white space : "/d1/d2 / d3". When I try to `git pull` the updates I get the following error :

> fatal: cannot create directory at '/d1/d2 / d3': No such file or directory

I tried : `git checkout --  '/d1/d2 / d3 /d4/file.ext'`
I've got the following error :

> error: pathspec '/d1/d2 / d3 /d4/file.ext' did not match any file(s) known to git

1. How can I safely update the path in remote ?
2. If it is not possible, how can I bypass this error ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try your checkout command with double quotes?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, which operating system and which command line are you using: windows 10 cmd prompt or linux git bash, etc, etc?

Comment: @AskyMcAskface yes I did try with double quotes, but didn't work

Comment: @mike I'm using windows10, and cmd line with linux git bash : MINGW64. I also tried with pycharm, and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

## Most likely to work

You can likely overcome this by creating the directories manually, one at a time, rather than a single command to make them all at once. In Git Bash:

```sh
$ mkdir "cd1/cd2 / cd3"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘cd1/cd2 / cd3’: No such file or directory

$ mkdir "cd1"
$ mkdir "cd1/cd2 "
$ mkdir "cd1/cd2 / cd3"
$ mkdir "cd1/cd2 / cd3/cd4"

$ cd cd1
$ ls
'cd2 '/

$ cd "cd2 "
$ ls
' cd3'/

etc.
```

This will make the directories already present when git tries to restore the files in them. Then the merge should complete okay.

It appears when the directories are chained together with spaces at the end (and/or beginning) that the mkdir command is choking when trying to create the intermediate directories. It probably isn't protecting the inner directory names when it splits them up, and the spaces are getting stripped.

### And if that doesn't work

If that doesn't work directly, split up the `git pull` command into `git fetch origin` and `git merge origin/master`. Then you'll have to futz with different ways of either merging into the remote `origin/master` branch or just resetting your local `master` branch to the new commit. After manually creating the folders as shown above, you should be able to pull in all the files from the new commit manually, then a soft reset of your master branch should work (note: merge into the commit prior to the problem one before doing this, if there are any between you and it).

### Deleting on the remote server

Incidentally, if you just want to delete the offending directories along with any files there, you can probably do that on the remote web interface. At least for Github you can delete and edit files and make new commits. Keep in mind that if you delete all the files in a directory, git doesn't save the actual directory itself so you may just need to delete the file(s) in the final directory.